# New photo events for Picasa

Tags: event-handling, google-plus, picasa

Presently I pull list of Picasa photos every 5 seconds using Google Data API - and compare against an old list.  When new files are added, e.g. 'sync'ed from Android device or uploaded by user using Google+, I may experience a lag (e.g. 5 seconds) before realizing the new photo and download/process it on my machine.

Does Picasa have a event model where it "pushes" news of a new photo using some API?

Answer (score 1):

There's no subscribe/push.    But, using the [feed](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/reference) can be optimized with a minimal query: only get the last item ([max-results](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/reference#Parameters) = 1) with minimal fields.    Then, if there's new content, go and fetch it as you already do.